# Redirect Externally After POST Request (Ruby on Rails 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, ruby-on-rails-7

In Rails 7, I am trying to use `redirect_to` to redirect the browser to an external website after that browser submits a POST request.

I have a view with a form:

```html
<!-- view/articles/new.html.erb -->
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_with model: @article do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :mystring %>
  <%= form.text_field :mystring %>
<% end %>
```

A controller:

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Do some active record stuff...
    redirect_to 'https://google.com', allow_other_host: true
  end
end
```

And my routes:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
end
```

I go to http://localhost:3000/articles/new, and enter the data into the form.  After submitting, the page simply reloads (in other words, I am still on http://localhost:3000/articles/new).  I do not get redirected to https://google.com, as I expect.

Doing the POST request in [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/), the redirect works without any issues.

Also, I tested what I believe would be the way to accomplish this in NodeJS (using Express), with the following code.  This redirect works in both browsers without any issue.

```
app.post('/articles/create', function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(302, {
    'Location': 'https://google.com'
  });
  res.end();
});
```

From my understanding, Rails is just writing a 'Location' header, same as I am doing manually in Express.  Rails does seem to write quite a few more headers than Express, however, so maybe one of those is what's causing the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: `redirect_to "https://google.com", allow_other_host: true` works perfectly so maybe you are not hitting the create action when you think you are, use some debug statements to prove the point, or maybe some exception is happening to prevent the create action from getting to that redirection line, again use some debug statements to check that what you t6hink is happening is what is actually happening. There is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: @jamesc Thanks for the reply.  Though I didn't mention it explicitly before, I am creating an object and saving it.  The redirect doesn't work, but the object does get created in the database, so I know I'm hitting the correct endpoint.  I went in with pry-rails just in case, though, and I am for sure hitting that point in the code.  On top of that, rails outputs: 
Redirected to https://google.com
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms | Allocations: 3746)

Comment: I'm not a rails expert but have you tried adding a status to your redirect? like `status: 303`

Comment: @ImanpalSingh not needed - [redirect_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) sets the response status - its `302 - Found` by default.  I think jamesc is right here and that this question can't actually be answered without code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I've tried setting the status code manually, from 301 - 307, but none of them worked.  Unfortunately, that code above does reproduce the error for me.  Would it help if I linked to a github repo with the full project code?

Comment: If it helps, my environment: MacOS 12.1, Ruby 3.1.1p18, Rails 7.0.2.3.

Comment: Did you solve it? Please share it with me.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I wasn't able to figure out why `redirect_to` wasn't working.  I just ended up switching to Rails 6 for this particular project, which works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, figured it out. You need to add `data: { turbo: false }` to your form method:

```
<%= form_with(model: article, method: :post, data: { turbo: false }) do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked on local with localhost:3000 not http://127.0.0.1:3000/ and in this format

```
    format.html { redirect_to(root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain), allow_other_host: true, notice: "Account was successfully updated.") }
```

Where as this did not

> ```
>     # format.html { redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain), allow_other_host: true, notice: "Account was successfully updated." }
> ```

[image: format.html { redirect_to(root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain), allow_other_host: true, notice: "Account was successfully updated.") }]

More info on the redirect here https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to